# Angular Overlay - MatSpinner Animation not working properly (PC/Firefox)

Tags: html, css, angular, firefox, angular-cdk

Note: I was only able to replicate the problem using Mozilla Firefox (67.0.4) on my PC(Ubuntu/Windows) . It was fine everywhere else.

The problem is the animation of the lowest progress spinner on [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mortom-progress-spinner-overlay). (StackBlitz)

First - Classic MatSpinner 
 Second - MatSpinner encapsulated in OverlayComponent 
 Third (bottom, left) - Loaded Overlay with OverlayComponent

Does anybody know why this is happening and if I can do something about it?